# I wonder how to use textarea to model in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use the model and send to the server.

For example, sending comments.

**comment.model.ts**

```
export interface Comment {
  article_no: number;
  username: string;
  nickname: string;
  creatat: Date;
  content: string;
}
```

**comment.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '.';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Comment } from '..';

@Injectable()
export class CommentService {

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  public writeComment(comment: Comment) {
    return this.apiService.post('/api/comment/', comment);
  }
}
```

**comment.component.html**
(I use material UI)

```
<form class="comment-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize [formControl]="content" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button class="ui primary button" (click)="addComment()"> Add </button>
  <button class="comment-btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

I've used [formControl], but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

**comment.component.ts**

```
...
export class CommentComponent implements DoCheck {
  content = new FormControl();
}
...
addComment() {
    this.commentService.writeComment(this.content.value);
}
```

I want to put 'this.content.value' in the 'content in comment.model.ts' and pass it to the server via comment.service.ts.

If you have a better way, I would appreciate your advice.

Thank you.

Comment: or use a formControl or use [(ngModel)]="your_variable-here". If the text-area  belong to a more complex form, you can use ReactiveForm, see https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since it is a form, a `formControl` is fine to user. If you want, you can also use **`[(ngModel)]`**. Change your template to following:

```
<form class="comment-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput matTextareaAutosize [(ngModel)]="content" placeholder="comment">
    </textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button class="ui primary button" (click)="addComment()"> Add </button>
  <button class="comment-btn">Save</button>
</form>
```

and typescript will look like this:

```
...
export class CommentComponent implements DoCheck {
  content: string;
}
...
addComment() {
    let comment: Comment = { content: this.content,
                             // You can initialize/set other properties as well
                           };
    this.commentService.writeComment(comment);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer has been helpful.